# Is it possible to move an image vertically up in only HTML (no CSS)?

Tags: html, image

The concerning script:

```
<img src="katjalogo.gif" alt="Katja Logo" height="150" width="200" style="float: left;">
```

I only want to move the image up a bit, without using CSS. Is this possible?

Comment: .......No.......

Comment: Try with <img align="top">

Comment: NO.  Things like this are what CSS is for.

Comment: Img align top is deprecated in HTML5 and should not be used. From W3C "The align attribute of <img> is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead."

Comment: @ArpitParasana the align attribute was deprecated in HTML 4 and deemed obsolete in 5.

Comment: Wow, have we come full circle?

Comment: what is the parent element? are you putting this directly in a body element or div..etc? why won't you use CSS? :) Check this out for easy answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090195/how-do-i-align-in-my-image-to-move-it-vertically-upcss-html